# Unable to subset (filter) a data frame due to NA's

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, subset

Why in the code below dplyr's `filter` doesn't return the same data.frame as base R subsetting?

In fact none of them works as expected. I'd like to remove observations/rows which, simultaneously, `b==1 AND c==1`. That is, I'd like to remove only the third row.

```
require(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(a=c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1),
  b=c(0,0,1,1,0,0,1),
  c=c(1,NA,1,NA,1,NA,NA))

filter(df, !(b==1 & c==1))

df[!(df$b==1 & df$c==1),]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or use `complete.cases` to convert `NA` to `FALSE` in the result logic vector so that you can pick the corresponding rows up after the negation, and this uses the fact that `NA & F = F`:

```
filter(df, !(b == 1 & c == 1 & complete.cases(df[c('b', 'c')])))

#   a b  c
# 1 0 0  1
# 2 0 0 NA
# 3 0 1 NA
# 4 1 0  1
# 5 1 0 NA
# 6 1 1 NA
```

More logical operations with `NA` involved here, which is a little bit confusing at the first glance but they are following the logic:

```
NA & F
# [1] FALSE
NA | T
# [1] TRUE
NA & T
# [1] NA
NA | F
# [1] NA
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the simplest option I can think of:

```
filter(df, !((b==1 & c==1) %in% TRUE))
#  a b  c
#1 0 0  1
#2 0 0 NA
#3 0 1 NA
#4 1 0  1
#5 1 0 NA
#6 1 1 NA

# or equivalently in data.table
dt[!((b==1 & c==1) %in% TRUE)]
```

Another, perhaps more verbose/clear option is to use `!(b==1 & c==1) | is.na(b+c)` as the comparison.

Comment: Nice. If `isTRUE` were vectorized, it would be a nice expression of this logic. I guess one could force the issue `df %>% filter(!Vectorize(isTRUE)(b == 1 & c == 1))`, but I'm not sure that's clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[df[,!(b==1 & c== 1& complete.cases(.SD[, c('b', 'c'), with = FALSE]))]]
#   a b  c
#1: 0 0  1
#2: 0 0 NA
#3: 0 1 NA
#4: 1 0  1
#5: 1 0 NA
#6: 1 1 NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `NA` values cause problems. Here's 4 workarounds:

**Method 1: 2-step Exclusion**

```
n <- (df$b+df$c==2)
df[n %in% c(NA, "FALSE"),]
```

> ```
>   a b  c
> 1 0 0  1
> 2 0 0 NA
> 4 0 1 NA
> 5 1 0  1
> 6 1 0 NA
> 7 1 1 NA
> ```

**Method 2: Conditional Sum**

```
df[!(complete.cases(df$b,df$c) & df$b+df$c == 2),]
```

> ```
>   a b  c
> 1 0 0  1
> 2 0 0 NA
> 4 0 1 NA
> 5 1 0  1
> 6 1 0 NA
> 7 1 1 NA
> ```

**Method 3: Loop/Function**

```
filterwithNA <- function(df,n){
  for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
    if(!is.na(df$b[i]) & !(is.na(df$c[i]))){
      if(df$b[i] == n & df$c[i] == n){
        df <- df[-i,]
      }
    }
  }
  return(df)
}

filterwithNA(df, n=1)
```

> ```
>   a b  c
> 1 0 0  1
> 2 0 0 NA
> 4 0 1 NA
> 5 1 0  1
> 6 1 0 NA
> 7 1 1 NA
> ```

**Method 4: Temporary numeric replacement**

```
df[is.na(df)] <- 999

df[!(df$b==1 & df$c==1),]
df[df==999] <- NA
df
```

> ```
>   a b  c
> 1 0 0  1
> 2 0 0 NA
> 4 0 1 NA
> 5 1 0  1
> 6 1 0 NA
> 7 1 1 NA
> ```

Comment: That is a solution, @Hack-R. I think it is not the best but it works. It seems to me R (and dplyr) should better deal with these kind of NAs, after all they are part of life.

Comment: @RodrigoRemedio Yes, `NA`'s cause problems all the time. Believe me, I understand.

Comment: @RodrigoRemedio I added 2 more solutions

Comment: @thelatemail no worries