# Subset a data frame using a vector, including NAs

Tags: r, dataframe

I'd like to get a subset of data frame rows where one of its columns is equal to the values in a vector, where either the vector or the data frame column can have NAs.  I'd like to include a match on NAs, but only if both column and vector have an NA.  (FYI, this is for a [labeller function](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/labeller.html) which gets a vector as a parameter.)

Some data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x_var_value=c('a', 'b', NA), num=c(1,2,3))
v2 <- c('a', 'b')
```

Some examples that don't work of trying to select rows from `df1` where `x_var_value == v2`:

```
df1[df1$x_var_value == v2]$x_var_value

df1[(df1$x_var_value == v2) | (is.na(df$x_var_value) & is.na(v2))]$x_var_value

library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% filter(x_var_value == v2)
```

I should be able to use the answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38948196/unable-to-subset-filter-a-data-frame-due-to-nas) or [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Comparing_vectors_or_factors_with_NA/), but somehow it eludes me.

**EDIT**: I think the labeller function probably wants output in the same order as input.  If so, I need the match in `v2` order.

**EDIT 2**: I also don't know if the labeller function will ever get passed variable values more than once.  Probably not?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that `== v2` is comparing x_var_value to a vector, rather than a single value, so what you need is to check if the value is *in* rather than *equal to* v2

```
df1[df1$x_var_value %in% v2,]
```

If v2 contains an NA, e.g. `v2 <- c('a', NA)` then it will include the rows that have NA in that column.

Comment: I think this answer will return these in order of df1. I think I need these in order of v2? (Edited the question.) I also wonder if the labeller function can ever be called with a vector that has var values twice (i.e., `v2=c('a', 'b', 'a', 'b')`.  I don't know the labeller interface well.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you just looking for `match`?

```r
df1[match(v2, df1$x_var_value),]
#>   x_var_value num
#> 1           a   1
#> 2           b   2
```

Comment: The question is a bit ambiguous - if the column of the data.frame contains mulitple a's then only the first one would be returned by this approach. It's not clear from the question whether all or just the first should be returned.

Comment: Good point @GavinKelly. Your approach using %in% would be better for multiple matches.

Comment: Good point. I don't know the labeller function behavior, whether it can pass in multiple of the same value. Also, whether it needs the return value in the same order as the original parameter (which it probably does), which makes me leery of `%in%`.

Comment: Note: this match answer returned two rows of all NAs for me, because the match itself returns all NAs.

Comment: @dfrankow why are your matches ‘NA’ ?

Comment: That's what the code does. See https://imgur.com/a/ZAEhAbt. Perhaps since df1$x_var_value has an NA in it.

Comment: The reason it's returning so many NAs is that you're not consistent in column names, you need `df1$col_value` in the match, as there isn't a column called x_var_value anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Another option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[as.character(x_var_value) %chin% v2]
```

Comment: Thanks! This did not work for me: https://imgur.com/a/SPq2kL0. But, I'm unlikely to use data.table, since I'd like to stick to the tidyverse.

Comment: Oh, my bad, not `col_value`. Still didn't work with the right var name: https://imgur.com/a/aNq78Td

Comment: @dfrankow you have a factor column, converted to character.  Please check my update